Page Keeps Loading in python selenium
When I open my homepage that page has some issues, and it loads correctly for the first two to three times, and then it takes time, lots of time, maybe above 1 minute. What I want is the page stop loading as all element appears on the first go, and start the next step.
I tried Implicit.wait but still getting errors.

First of all, it is not possible to help without seeing your code and/or error. Also, what is the purpose of testing a web page that is unstable?
